# Compare two collections with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, collections, comparison

I have two collections from Type, say something like this:

```
MyType
{
    public bool isDifferent = false;
    private string str;
    public int n;
}

ObservableCollection<MyType> c1;
ObservableCollection<MyType> c2;
```

I want to compare c1 and c2 and if they are different to set isDifferent of c1 to True and isDifferent of c2 to stay like this. How to achieve this with LINQ. I am also wondering how will the comparing happen when the isDifferent will always not be the same. Maybe some exclude linq clause spesifically for isDifferent memeber.

Comment: When are two `MyType` instances equal?

Comment: Linq is *to ask a question*, not to *perform an action on a collection*. So split up what you want to do in two parts, the question (are these sets different?) and the action (set a property/field).

Comment: possibly you need [Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource> Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx), or [Enumerable.SequenceEqual<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TSource>, IEqualityComparer<TSource>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342073(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

LINQ provides [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) method that lets you walk two collections in a single loop:

```
foreach (var p in c1.Zip(c2, (a, b) => new {a, b}) {
    // p.a represents the first element; p.b is the second element
    if (!CompareMyType(p.a, p.b)) {
        // Set properties of p.a or p.b here:
        p.a.isDifferent = true;
    }
}
```

Note that this code lets you test for pairwise equality based on the sequence of items in both collections, so the ordering inside your collections is important.

Answer (score 0):

In **Linq** try something like this. Although you didnt tell the business involved in comparing the collection

```
c1.Except(c2).Union(c2.Except(c1)).Select(your properties);
```

Using SymmetricExceptWith

```
var c1= new HashSet<T>(a);
var c2 = new HashSet<T>(b);
c1.SymmetricExceptWith(c2);
```

Comment: How does `Except`, `Union` or `HashSet<MyType>` know which objects are equal? Apart from that, i assume OP wants to update the `IsDifferent` for `c1`(_"set isDifferent of c1 to True and isDifferent of c2 to stay like this"_).

Comment: agree with you. actually what i thought is OP wants to compare the two lists and pop out the similar items from both the collection.